# Getting more information about an object when clicking on a text in html using MVC

Tags: java, html, servlets, model-view-controller

So I'm a making a small web app to get information about games, I have made a searchBar that request the search to an API and then I get the first 10 games with the most similar title to the search. But I only show the title.

[This is an example of a search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7VE7.png)

The games have a lot of attributes, one of them is the ID, and it allows me to get all the info of a game using a controller.

Right now the app works like this:
1: You search the title of a game
2. A controller gives me a List of IDs and with the ids I get the rest of the info about the games, but I only show the titles.

Now, what I want to do:
3.When you click on a title you use a controller, and from the ID it request (again, I'm not sure if I can use the previous games objects) all the info from that game and Shows it.

The controllers works fine, but I'm having problems with the HTML.

This is the controller for the search:

```
...
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {   

    String query = request.getParameter("searchQuery");
    RequestDispatcher rd = null;  

    log.log(Level.FINE, "Searching for games that contain " + query);
    GameResource game = new GameResource();
    GameSearch[] gameResults = null;
    gameResults = game.getGameSearch(query);

    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(gameResults));
    List<Game> listaBusqueda = new ArrayList<Game>();

    if (gameResults.length!=0){
        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/success.jsp");
        for (GameSearch g : gameResults) {
            listaBusqueda.add(game.getGame(g.getId().toString()));
        }
        request.setAttribute("games", listaBusqueda);
    } else {
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Game object: " + gameResults);
        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/error.jsp");
    }
    rd.forward(request, response);

}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
}
...
```

This is the controllers that gives me a game using an ID

```
...
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String gameId = request.getParameter("id");
    GameResource resource = new GameResource();
    RequestDispatcher rd = null;
    log.log(Level.FINE, "Retrieving game");

    Game game = resource.getGame(gameId);

    if(game!=null) {
        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/success.jsp");
        request.setAttribute("Game", game);
        request.setAttribute("Item", "gameID");
    } else {
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Cannot retrieve game: ");
        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/error.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
  }

}
```

Both of them works, in the last one the objects are created correctly and the ID is obtained.

Now, this is the html for success.jsp, and this is where the problem is:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Search results</title>
</head>
<body>


<fieldset id="IGDB">
    <legend>
        IGDB search for
        <c:out value="${param.searchQuery}" />
    </legend>

    <c:forEach items="${requestScope.games}" var="game">
        <article name="gameArticle" id="gameArticle"></article>
        <a href="GameIdController?id=${game.id}"><c:out value="${game.name}" 
/></a>

        <br />
    </c:forEach>
</fieldset>

<c:if test="${requestScope.Item=='gameID' }">
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.Game}" var="game">
        <article name="gameArticle" id="gameArticle"></article>
        <c:out value="${game.name}" />

        <br />
    </c:forEach>
    $game = ${requestScope.Game}
    <c:out value="${game.name}"/>

</c:if>

<article name = "gameByIDArticle" id = "gameByIDArticle">

</article>

</body>
</html>
```

When I click in a title, I get redirected to a blank webpage (http://localhost:8090/GameIdController?id=IdOfTheGame),as you can see the id is included in the URL, but it's completely blank and it should include the title again as is stated in my code.

I will also include my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>GameSearchController</display-name>
    <servlet-name>GameSearchController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>aiss.controller.GameSearchController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GameSearchController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/GameSearchController</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>GamePopularityController</display-name>
    <servlet-name>GamePopularityController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>aiss.controller.GamePopularityController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GamePopularityController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/GamePopularityController</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/api</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet- 


 class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
</servlet- 
class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>aiss.api.GameApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>GameIdController</display-name>
    <servlet-name>GameIdController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>aiss.controller.GameIdController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GameIdController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/GameIdController</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

Comment: what is the URL before clicking on a title and after clicking?

Comment: Before: http://localhost:8090/GameIdController  After: http://localhost:8090/GameIdController?id=IdOfTheGame

Comment: post your web.xml or servlet annotations for this too.

Comment: Done, I noticed that I had a " * " there, as can be seen in the post that was commenting a lot of lines, but still doesn't work even if I delete it

Comment: found your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay i think i understand why you are seeing a blank page. Everything is working as expected, the problem seems to be with this:

```
if(game!=null) {
    rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/success.jsp");
    request.setAttribute("Game", game);
    request.setAttribute("Item", "gameID");
} else {
    log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Cannot retrieve game: ");
    rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/error.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

The reason why you are seeing a blank page is because your game variable is not null. And you don't have a forward statement in the first part of that if else block.

```
if(game!=null) {
    rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/success.jsp");
    request.setAttribute("Game", game);
    request.setAttribute("Item", "gameID");
    rd.forward(request, response); // missing this!
} else {
    log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Cannot retrieve game: ");
    rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/error.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

**EDIT:** In response to your other problem from the comment, i think the forEach is having problems because of this:

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.Game}" var="game">
```

change it to this:

```
<c:forEach items="${Game}" var="game">
```

Comment: It's strange, now the URL is still "http://localhost:8090/GameIdController?id=ID", but I'm viewing the error.jsp servlet

Comment: hmm yeah that's weird, try switching around the if condition, check if game is null instead of not null. But you're no longer seeing a blank page correct?

Comment: Now the error I'm getting is: "Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in &lt;forEach&gt;" So I guess the HTML is still wrong

Comment: cool, thanks. It's easy to miss out small things like that, happens to the best of us. Not sure why you are getting the error page though, that's super strange. Let us know why that happened when you figure it out!

Comment: I edited my last comment in case you didn't see, it seems that the HTML in success.jsp is still wrong somehow

Comment: hmm, check out my edited answer, maybe that will help. you don't need to include "requestScope"

Comment: It finally works, thank you very much, one strange thing is that it doesn't show me the attribute "name" it just shows me the Game.toString()